# how to stop state change to render material-ui table in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

the next part of codes are inside my app.js:
I got this state:

```
const [open,setOpen] = useState(false)
```

which is used to determine if a material-ui Alert should appear on the screen for 3 second with this code:

```
useEffect(()=>{
     setTimeout(()=> {
        setOpen(false)
     },3000)
},[open])
```

and returned as:

```
<Collapse in ={open}>
  <Alert severity={severity}>
    {alertMessage}
  </Alert>
</Collapse>
```

setOpen sent to the component Table as prop

```
<Table
loading={loading}
data={data}
setAlertState={setOpen}
/>
```

the next parts are in Table.js:
in table.js I am working with:

```
import{
 useGridApiRef,
 DataGridPro,
 GridOverlay,
 GridActionsCellItem,
 useGridState
} from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';
```

when I click to edit the row and then save this function run(this is not the full function ofc):

```
const handleSaveclick = (id) =>async(event)=>{
   if(validate_edit())
   {
      apiRef.current.updateRow([{...row}]);
      handleAlert("success","Word edited!");
   }
```

handleAlert:

```
const handleAlert = (severity,alertMessage)=>
{
   setSeverity(()=>severity);
   setAlertMessage(()=>alertMessage);
   setAlertState(()=>true);
}
```

well the problem is that my data grid table updates himself, but when the alert goes true/false the table returns to what was before.

how to handle this render?
what I do wrong?
thanks in advance.

Comment: in the effect put a condition, `if(open){setTimeout ....}`

Comment: changed it, doesnt help.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue using stackblitz or codesandbox?

Comment: Please provide information how components structure looks like and also where data is taken from. I can only speculate that Alert is causing DataGrid to rerender and it is rerendered with old data object, meaning all the updates disappear,

Answer (score 0):

Without a full example, it will be hard to solve.

Most of the time such bugs appear when you rerender the DataGrid. You have two solutions:

- avoid rerendering. Can not be more precise without example
- control the data you want to keep them up to date